# Playing video (on iPhone) which has been streamed via a custom protocol?

Tags: iphone

I need to play video that has been streamed by a custom protocol, *not* via HTTP live streaming (in fact not via HTTP at all). While I have no problems implementing the protocol, I can't see how to set up a player so that I can just feed the stream to it (and have it decode and display the video) - instead the API always requires I provide a URL.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I never found a way, but it is possible to use an internal web server (so the URL is `http://127.0.0.1:xxx`) and feed a stream to the decoder that way. An MPEG Transport Stream (.ts) worked well for my case, though it did mean writing a muxer.